# ASP.NET with Bootstrap modal as javascript confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to override the default javascript confirm popups with a Bootstrap modal.
But I cant make it work with ASP.net's property for most controls: "OnClientClick".

Here's the aspx content relevant:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-danger fullwidth"
           OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" CommandName="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
window.confirm = function (message, callback, caption) {
    confirmResponse = undefined
    caption = caption || 'Confirm'
    message = message.replace("\n", "<br />");
    var modalContainer, modalHeader, modalBody, modalFooter;
    /* Create modal if doesnt allready exists (to avoid dublicate modals) */
    if ($("#confirmation-modal").length != 1) {
        modalContainer = $('<div>').attr({ 'class': 'modal fade', 'id': 'confirmation-modal' });
        var modalDialog = $('<div>').attr({ 'class': 'modal-dialog' });
        var modalContent = $('<div>').attr({ 'class': 'modal-content' });
        modalHeader = $('<div>').attr({ 'class': 'modal-header' });
        modalBody = $('<div>').attr({ 'class': 'modal-body' });
        modalFooter = $('<div>').attr({ 'class': 'modal-footer' });

        modalContainer.html($(modalDialog));
        modalDialog.html($(modalContent));
        modalContent.html($(modalHeader));
        modalContent.append($(modalBody));
        modalContent.append($(modalFooter));
    } else {
        modalContainer = $("#confirmation-modal");
        modalHeader = $("#confirmation-modal .modal-header");
        modalBody = $("#confirmation-modal .modal-body");
        modalFooter = $("#confirmation-modal .modal-footer");
    }
    /* Set content of modal */
    modalHeader.html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><h4 class="modal-title">' + caption + '</h4>');
    modalBody.html('<p>' + message + '</p>');
    var modalTrueBtn = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Yes</button>').click(function () {
        if (callback != undefined) callback();
        console.log("confirm returned true");
        return true;
    });
    var modalFalseBtn = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>').click(function () {
        console.log("confirm returned false");
        return false;
    });
    modalFooter.html(modalTrueBtn).append(modalFalseBtn);
    /* show modal */
    modalContainer.modal();
};
```

The part of the code that creates the modal is fine. It pop's up just fine, but it doesnt return true/false.

Comment: have a look at [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/), I recently begin to use it also for confirmation dialogs and other stuff. Its very easy to use which minimal of code

Comment: I've read about Bootbox almost every time i googled for a solution for my problem, but I wanted some that i could style myself. But thanks for the response

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: on the button you either have OnClientClick="openMyModal()" or you put in the code behind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "none", "openMyModal()", True)
```

Step 2: Either call a javascript/jQuery function from your modal OK button, or put runat="server" on your modal OK button to make it postback and put appropriate code there to carry out your action.

I did not originally show the Bootstrap modal markup along with the openMyModal function for clarity but such a function would look like this:

```
function openMyModal() {
    $('#myModal').modal({
        show: true
    })
}
```

Comment: I can only think this is marked down because I didn't include an example and / or I didn't answer the question directly. I think this is an example of the direct answer to the question: https://gist.github.com/jnormore/7418776.